# analizador lexico reconocer palabra

Tags: python

estoy realizando un analizador léxico en Python para distinguir prolog, a lo que me lleva a mi problema y es que en prolog si la primera letra es mayúscula esta será variable, mientras que si no, es constante, por lo que ocupando la librería de ply.lex, cree lo siguiente, más algo sacado por GitHub en la parte final (https://github.com/maryito/Analisis-lexico-sintactico-Python/blob/master/analizador_lexico.py), el tema es que leyendo por la web de Microsoft sobre lenguajes de expresión, no logro hacer que me tome la palabra entera, por ejemplo "HOla", lo toma como "HO" es Variable y "la" es constante, las distingue de maravilla, pero necesito que sea la palabra entera, y no veo el error, agradezco la ayuda y guía.

```
import ply.lex as lex

# resultado del analisis
resultado_lexema = []

reservada = (
    # Palabras Reservadas

   'CADENA',

)
tokens = reservada + (
    'CONSTANTE',
    'VARIABLE',

)

def t_VARIABLE(t):
    r'[A-Z_]+(\w\d)*'
    return t

def t_CONSTANTE(t):
    r'[a-z]+(\d\w)*'
    return t


def t_CADENA(t):
   r'\"?(\w+ \ *\w*\d* \ *)\"?'
   return t


def t_error( t):
    global resultado_lexema
    estado = "** Token no valido en la Linea {:4} Valor {:16} Posicion {:4}".format(str(t.lineno), str(t.value),
                                                                      str(t.lexpos))
    resultado_lexema.append(estado)
    t.lexer.skip(1)

# Prueba de ingreso
def prueba(data):
    global resultado_lexema

    analizador = lex.lex()
    analizador.input(data)

    resultado_lexema.clear()
    while True:
        tok = analizador.token()
        if not tok:
            break
        # print("lexema de "+tok.type+" valor "+tok.value+" linea "tok.lineno)
        estado = "Linea {:4} Tipo {:16} Valor {:16} Posicion {:4}".format(str(tok.lineno),str(tok.type) ,str(tok.value), str(tok.lexpos) )
        resultado_lexema.append(estado)
    return resultado_lexema

 # instanciamos el analizador lexico
analizador = lex.lex()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        data = input("ingrese: ")
        prueba(data)
        print(resultado_lexema)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La idea es que tome la palabra HOla como variable, y no que la separe en dos partes, como lo esta devolviendo el código.

Comment: Me da `ERROR: No token list is defined` cuando intento ejecutar el código. Recuerda que debes publicar un código reproducible, mínimo. También tienes que dar el resultado esperado, para validar la solución.

Comment: @CandidMoe Sorry, ahí si agregue todo el código y foto de lo que me está devolviendo.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que en las expresiones regulares

```
r'[A-Z_]+(\w\d)*'
r'[a-z]+(\d\w)*'
```

tienes un asterico al final. El astericos significa **cero** o más.

Por tanto, "HOla" comienza con dos caracteres que son reconocidos por el primer patrón: Una o más mayúsculas seguidas de cero o más cualquier otra cosa.

Con el segundo patrón, misma historia. Le bastan con ver dos minúsculas al principio y ya sabe que cumple con el patrón. Lo que resta es ver hasta donde cumple ...

Con el patrón de cadenas:

```
r'\"?(\w+ \ *\w*\d* \ *)\"?'
```

el problema es el `?`, que significa **cero** o uno. Mismo traspiés: las cremillas son opcionales según este patrón. [No entiendo el propósito de lo que va entre paréntesis, pero no no calza con nada reconocible].

No me queda claro porque usas un *grupo de captura* en las expresiones regulares en lugar de `[]` para indicar un conjunto de caracteres. Sin eso no puedo ofrecer una solución alternativa.

Mi consejo (si puedes) es que escribas el analizador a mano, porque ya tienes una muestra del sufrimiento que te espera cada día. Por ejemplo, cuando tengas que reconocer un string multilinea con cremillas escapadas:

```
mensaje = "Hola, \"amigo\"\n" \
          "¿Qué te trae por acá?"
```

No se si existan en Prolog, pero a ver quien escribe una expresión regular para eso.